# Cassandra-Hector InvalidRequestException

Tags: java, cassandra, hector

I'm trying to create a Cassandra database based on what I found
[here](https://github.com/rantav/hector/wiki/Getting-started-%285-minutes%29).

but no matter what I do, I am keep getting this error

> **Caused by:** me.prettyprint.hector.api.exceptions.HInvalidRequestException: InvalidRequestException(why:Keyspace names must be case-insensitively unique ("myKeyspace" conflicts with "myKeyspace")

Here's my code:

```
public static void setSerializedMap(int index,String serializedVector){
    Cluster cluster = HFactory.getOrCreateCluster("TestCluster", "localhost:9160");

    ColumnFamilyDefinition columnFamilyDefinition=HFactory.createColumnFamilyDefinition("myKeyspace", "user", ComparatorType.BYTESTYPE);
    KeyspaceDefinition keyspaceDefinition=HFactory.createKeyspaceDefinition("myKeyspace",ThriftKsDef.DEF_STRATEGY_CLASS,3,Arrays.asList(columnFamilyDefinition));
    cluster.addKeyspace(keyspaceDefinition,true);

    Keyspace keyspace=HFactory.createKeyspace("Keyspace", cluster);

    Mutator<String> mutator = HFactory.createMutator(keyspace, me.prettyprint.cassandra.serializers.StringSerializer.get());
    try{
        mutator.addInsertion("cluster", "user", HFactory.createStringColumn("cluster-" + index, serializedVector));
    }catch(HectorException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

Any suggestions on how to fix it?

Answer (score 2):

Check to see if "myKeyspace" exists before you try to create it, you cannot create it if its already there.

```
if (cluster.describeKeyspace("myKeyspace") == null) { ...
```

It may create race conditions in your code though if called from multiple places/nodes around time of creation. This is resolved in CQL if you can upgrade.

If using CQL you can use "CREATE KEYSPACE *IF NOT EXISTS* blarg WITH ...".  Although if using cql may want to consider moving from hector to one of the libraries which are designed for it.